# Is Memory consumption is also Dynamic just like CPU for Docker Containers

Tags: docker

I want to run multiple containers on a single host by providing limits on CPU & Memory. If my host has 1024 cpu shares & I assign them as 512 & 512 to two containers, it means that the first container can take as much as 1024 if second container is not using any cpu. But if both of them are using cpu, then both get limited to 512.

Is it also true for memory usage? Or somehow can I set it that way?
Here is the scenario: 
I have 1024 Mb of RAM available for containers and I have two containers, I want each one to take 512 Mb of RAM but should be able to extend to more than 512 if other container is not using it. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of memory you provide to Docker a fixed amount of memory (and swap) in bytes, kilobytes, megabytes,..., and that amount will limit the memory that container can allocate, no matter if the host has memory free or if it is being used by other process.

When limiting the memory it's important taking care of how Docker (or cgroups) limit the memory and swap of the container. From Docker v1.5 (and fixed in v1.6) Docker lets limit the memory and swap independently. Check [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory) to more details about this.

Comment: Does it mean a container with memory limit of 512Mb can actually consume 800Mb in case it is available?

Comment: If you run `docker run ... -m 512m ...` the max amount of memory used that container will be 512Mb and, if you don't specify `--memory-swap` option, it will let you to use another 512Mb of swap (if your host system has swap available). Running `docker run ... -m 512m --memory-swap=512m...` will let the container to use 512Mb of ram and no extra swap... But these constrains are fixed not matter if the host machine is idle and has idle resources.